# redirect_to , relationship between controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I generated a scaffold and it makes a controller that looks like this (I stripped some code out but it still works).

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end
```

This causes it to redirect to /posts/**id** which all works fine.

But I don't understand how this works. `@post` is an instance of a model class, so how does it know which controller and action it should redirect to? I don't see anywhere that this relationship is explicitly defined (between `Post` model and `PostsController`).

I have tried replicated this from scratch without scaffolding and I get errors about being unable to find `url_for` associated with the models I define. Even when I do define routes with `resources` in `routes.rb`.

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb` or the output of `rake routes`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `redirect_to` it calculates path by calling [`_compute_redirect_to_location`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L74) method

And reaches the `else` statement in [that method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting.rb#L105)

And calling `url_for` method where [reaches `else`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L111) as well.

And calls `polymorphic_path` (and `polymorphic_url`) [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L135).

Here `convert_to_model(record)` [method has been called](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L100).

Where [`record == @post`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L160)

Calculating the `inflection` you will [reach `else`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L116) and it's `:singular`

After you will [reach `build_named_rout_call`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L120)

And calls [`ActiveModel::Naming.singular_route_key(@post)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L186).
You will get `['post']`

After [`route << routing_type(options)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L194) your route is `['post', :url]`

Putting [`@post` into `args`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L127) and [send("post_url", args)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L129) which is same as`post_path(@post)`

I'm sorry if I'm wrong somewhere. I hope this will give you understanding of `redirect_to @post`.

Comment: Wowww could not be more precise : )

Answer (score 0):

The reason it still works because in your controller Post create method is still there, which looks normal to me and also in your routes.rb file you probably have something like resources: posts which covers all your controller actions such as posts/1/ etc. Another thing is to make sure you restart your server when you edit/change your routes.eb file. Hope this is clear enough to understand.